# HTML/CSS/JS: Max-Height being misrecognized and not applied on transitions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

So let's say I have a blue square and a compressed red-box:

[image]

So I want that, when I click on the square, the red-box readapts it's size to it's current content:

[image]

And when I click again on the square, I want the red box to return to it's original state:

[image]

And I want both movements to happen slowly, with the `transition` property.

So I have two problems: First, the transition is not working at any of the steps. Second, once I bring the box once to it's original state, I can't make it enlarge anymore.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="red_box">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam commodo, ipsum non ultrices pulvinar, turpis nulla sollicitudin leo, vitae convallis orci velit sed ante. In sodales sed lorem in blandit. Proin ornare cursus tortor, at tincidunt libero. Nulla in ex in augue iaculis congue ut egestas odio. Morbi tristique varius lorem, id dictum magna convallis eget. Nulla sit amet massa eu tortor facilisis dapibus. Phasellus nec porttitor enim. Donec vitae pharetra nibh. Nam convallis arcu et rutrum fringilla.

    Curabitur at mauris pharetra, ultrices tortor quis, congue tortor. In nec ornare eros. Morbi imperdiet luctus sem sit amet pellentesque. Maecenas ac accumsan sapien. Vivamus eu dui tristique, pharetra ex id, tincidunt est. Nulla viverra eu mi fringilla blandit. Ut sagittis quam nisl. In eu rutrum ex. Ut ac ante id nibh aliquam ultrices quis vel arcu. Donec molestie ipsum sapien, sed pellentesque lectus ornare sit amet. Maecenas vitae turpis arcu. Praesent ac faucibus sapien. Quisque ornare venenatis pulvinar. In felis metus, posuere non convallis id, commodo sed lorem.

    Maecenas porta risus sed ipsum luctus mattis. Integer faucibus placerat justo, sed lobortis est gravida tincidunt. Aliquam ut aliquet sem, et sodales enim. Vivamus rhoncus sodales felis a fermentum. Phasellus pellentesque fringilla lorem ut lobortis. Maecenas erat urna, viverra et egestas consectetur, eleifend vel sem. Praesent fermentum vehicula porttitor. Duis faucibus gravida nulla non volutpat. Nam tincidunt ligula in nisi efficitur, a ultricies magna aliquam. Morbi commodo posuere egestas. Maecenas quis orci interdum velit elementum lacinia nec ac dolor. Nullam sodales magna at dui pharetra efficitur.

    Nulla ultricies eros et ex tempus, eu faucibus orci dapibus. In ac sapien ornare, malesuada velit id, congue augue. Cras metus lectus, molestie id leo maximus, accumsan fermentum elit. Aliquam congue malesuada iaculis. Donec tempus enim quis tortor tristique finibus. Curabitur sed sapien quis felis venenatis porttitor quis sed dui. Phasellus in commodo orci. Vestibulum tempor purus vitae ultrices condimentum. Mauris mattis erat sed nunc suscipit tincidunt.

    Quisque porttitor dolor vel faucibus molestie. Quisque sollicitudin accumsan ipsum, a ultrices lectus dignissim interdum. Integer vestibulum mauris vitae purus suscipit, ut rutrum ante vehicula. Sed sollicitudin lectus eu justo commodo aliquet. Etiam rhoncus tellus sed diam aliquam consequat. Aenean tristique, dolor et dignissim rhoncus, turpis urna euismod elit, ac commodo nulla purus id tellus. Aliquam suscipit consequat vestibulum.

    Phasellus massa ex, pharetra nec augue eu, blandit volutpat ligula. Duis finibus nulla nunc, vitae ultrices nibh sollicitudin ac. Donec consectetur quam eu turpis dapibus, ut egestas arcu condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque posuere tincidunt sem, at fermentum leo efficitur vitae. Maecenas mattis erat quis urna accumsan, vel elementum felis pellentesque. Etiam id pretium ex. Suspendisse arcu turpis, blandit rutrum mi eu, volutpat tincidunt nunc. Duis pretium, augue in faucibus convallis, turpis nulla tempus metus, at ornare dolor turpis ac elit. Ut dapibus diam vel sem aliquet aliquet id nec sapien. Sed dictum eu ligula quis dictum. Curabitur blandit neque eu nibh vestibulum, eget tincidunt nibh aliquam.

    Nulla molestie ultricies sem, nec pharetra mi pharetra ac. Mauris aliquam vestibulum augue et convallis. Nunc rutrum quis felis at fermentum. Integer non mauris a augue finibus laoreet. Etiam dignissim tincidunt porttitor. Phasellus dignissim turpis eget accumsan hendrerit. Praesent nisl urna, semper nec luctus non, dignissim quis enim. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus elit lacus, rutrum et volutpat ac, hendrerit eu ante. Phasellus vitae erat ante. Aenean pulvinar libero eu magna auctor aliquet. Morbi facilisis, erat eu bibendum aliquet, dui augue mattis nisl, non bibendum lorem lorem sit amet odio. Vestibulum elit orci, posuere nec iaculis at, maximus quis libero.


    </div>

    <div id="square"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#red_box{

width:40%;
max-height:0px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:white;
color:black;
border:5px double red;
position:relative;
left:55%;
transition:max-height 1s, overflow 1s;
display:inline-block;
}

#square{
float:left;
width:200px;
height:150px;
background-color:blue;


}
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector("#square").onclick = set_red_box;

function set_red_box(){
       if(document.querySelector("#red_box").style.maxHeight == 0){
          grow_red_box();
    }
    else{
        diminish_red_box();
    }
}

function grow_red_box(){
      document.querySelector("#red_box").style.maxHeight = "5000000px";
      document.querySelector("#red_box").style.overflow = "auto";
}

function diminish_red_box(){
      document.querySelector("#red_box").style.maxHeight = "0";
      document.querySelector("#red_box").style.overflow = "hidden";
```

}

And the JFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rerr6ra8/2/

Comment: the fiddle is not correct

Comment: you can not animate max-height property. Use just height. Set height to 0, than on show set height to auto, calculate height and set to 0 again, than use calculated height to animate to that height.

Comment: @cocoa thanks, just corrected!

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze sorry, could you explain it better?

Comment: @MrGuliarte: with **[TweenMax](http://greensock.com/gsap)**, it looks like **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/kps7rep6/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use transitions this way because the height depends on the content in the box (`auto`). This is not supported by CSS transitions. However the `max-height` property is perfectly able to use with animations.

What you can do, is calculate the height with JavaScript and use that in with your code:

```
var redbox = document.getElementById('red_box');
var height = redbox.clientHeight;
redbox.style.maxHeight = "0px";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rerr6ra8/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate an unknown `height` using transition, which means that `height: auto` doesn't work, you need to set height explicitly.

However, as you are using JS to change `height`, you can set the height to be equal to the [`scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight), which is (mdn):

> The Element.scrollHeight read-only attribute is a measurement of the
>   height of an element's content, including content not visible on the
>   screen due to overflow.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/L4epfqdy/1/)

```
document.querySelector("#square").onclick = set_red_box;
var redBox = document.querySelector("#red_box");
var open = false; // redBox state used for toggle

function set_red_box() {
    if (open) {
        redBox.style.height = '0';
    } else {
        redBox.style.height = redBox.scrollHeight + 'px'; // scrollHeight is the full content height
    }

    open = !open;
}
```

CSS:

```
#red_box {
    width:40%;
    height: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:white;
    color:black;
    border:5px double red;
    position:relative;
    left:55%;
    transition: height 1s; /** change transition to height **//
    display:inline-block;
}
```